# Pixi.js zoom / not re-rendering sprites?

Tags: javascript, webgl, pixi.js

I am learning pixi.js, intending to use it to render a large directed graph with many nodes. I forked a codepen that had something similar, but when I use a simple circle texture for sprites, and when I zoom in, the edges get blurry:

[image]

```
function makeParicleTexture(props) {
  const gfx = new PIXI.Graphics();
  gfx.beginFill(props.fill);
  gfx.lineStyle(props.strokeWidth, props.stroke);
  gfx.drawCircle(props.size / 2, props.size / 2, 3)
  gfx.endFill();

  const texture = app.renderer.generateTexture(gfx, PIXI.SCALE_MODES.LINEAR, 2);
  return texture;
}
```

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/mfbridges/pen/xxRqGRz

How can I ask pixi.js to re-rasterize the circle at this new zoom level so that edges of the circle are crisp when you zoom in?

I have seen many examples where this happens seemingly automatically (e.g. here: https://bl.ocks.org/pkerpedjiev/cf791db09ebcabaec0669362f4df1776) so I'm confused why it's not working in the codepen above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have seen many examples where this happens seemingly automatically (e.g. here: https://bl.ocks.org/pkerpedjiev/cf791db09ebcabaec0669362f4df1776) so I'm confused why it's not working in the codepen above.

It works there because they just draw "Graphics" object (no texture):

```
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

graphics.beginFill(0xe74c3c); // Red
d3.range(numCircles).map(function() {
    graphics.drawCircle(randomX(), randomY(), 1);
});

stage.addChild(graphics);
```

"Graphics" are always "scaling" correctly because they are calculated on each render (i think). But textures are generated once and then reused.

What can help in your code:

- make bigger Texture and then scale the Sprite that is created from it

```
gfx.drawCircle(props.size / 2, props.size / 2, 3)
// make radius bigger:
gfx.drawCircle(props.size / 2, props.size / 2, 30)

//then in "makeSprites" function add this line somewhere after Sprite is created:
sprite.scale.set(0.1, 0.1);
```

^ see: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/16601-resize-texture/

- increase "resolution" of texture ( "*The resolution / device pixel ratio of the texture being generated.*" - https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.AbstractRenderer.html#generateTexture )  :

```
const texture = app.renderer.generateTexture(gfx, PIXI.SCALE_MODES.LINEAR, 2);
// change to:
const texture = app.renderer.generateTexture(gfx, PIXI.SCALE_MODES.LINEAR, 20);
```

You need to exepriment and decide which way to use :)